# CAS and LDAP custom integration

Tags: ldap, cas

I'm going to describe an odd situation..  We have a product with a properly working CAS and LDAP integration.  The problem is that not all of our clients use LDAP, which is fine, EXCEPT that the integration is still in place and so CAS is actively attempting to connect to the ldap server (and failing of course).  It attempts to connect every five minutes, which creates a very bloated Tomcat log. My goal is to prevent it from attempting to connect without gutting the integration.  I'm hoping someone knows of a way to prevent or manage when/how CAS attempts to connect to the defined LDAP server.

I've attempted to remove key components of the CAS property file as well as the deployerConfigContext.xml but the integration has too many dependencies, and I haven't been successful.

Here are some of the properties that are used in the cas.properties file.  Setting the ldap.auth.enabled to false allows our integration to not use LDAP when authenticating the user but doesn't prevent CAS from attempting to connect to the LDAP server:

```
ldap.auth.enabled=false
ldap.url=ldap://xyz.customurl.com
ldap.useStartTLS=false
ldap.rootDn=DC=xyz,DC=xyz,DC=com
ldap.baseDn=DC=xyz,DC=xyz,DC=com
ldap.connectTimeout=3000
ldap.managerDn=CN=xyz,CN=Users,DC=xyz,DC=xyz,DC=com
ldap.managerPassword=xyz
ldap.authn.searchFilter=(&(sAMAccountName={user})(objectClass=user))
ldap.domain=123.456.7.890
ldap.pool.minSize=1
ldap.pool.maxSize=10
ldap.pool.validateOnCheckout=false
ldap.pool.validatePeriodically=true
ldap.pool.blockWaitTime=3000
ldap.pool.validatePeriod=300
ldap.pool.prunePeriod=300
ldap.pool.idleTime=600
ldap.usePpolicy=false
ldap.allowMultipleDns=true
```

This is the relevant section from the deployerConfigContext.xml.  I've tried commenting the entire ldap section but have received various other errors that caused TomCat to crash:

```
<bean id="ldapAuthenticationHandler"
      class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.LdapAuthenticationHandler"
      p:principalIdAttribute="sAMAccountName"
      c:authenticator-ref="authenticator" lazy-init="true"/>

<ldaptive:ad-authenticator id="authenticator"
                           ldapUrl="${ldap.url}"
                           userFilter="${ldap.authn.searchFilter}"
                           bindDn="${ldap.managerDn}"
                           bindCredential="${ldap.managerPassword}"
                           allowMultipleDns="${ldap.allowMultipleDns:false}"
                           connectTimeout="${ldap.connectTimeout}"
                           validateOnCheckOut="${ldap.pool.validateOnCheckout}"
                           failFastInitialize="false"
                           blockWaitTime="${ldap.pool.blockWaitTime}"
                           idleTime="${ldap.pool.idleTime}"
                           baseDn="${ldap.baseDn}"
                           maxPoolSize="${ldap.pool.maxSize}"
                           minPoolSize="${ldap.pool.minSize}"
                           validatePeriodically="${ldap.pool.validatePeriodically}"
                           validatePeriod="${ldap.pool.validatePeriod}"
                           prunePeriod="${ldap.pool.prunePeriod}"
                           useSSL="${ldap.use.ssl:false}"
                           subtreeSearch="${ldap.subtree.search:true}"
                           useStartTLS="${ldap.useStartTLS}"/>
```

The stack trace for the CAS to LDAP server connection is huge.  Here is a small snippet.  I can attach the whole thing if that is useful.

> org.ldaptive.provider.ConnectionException:
>   javax.naming.CommunicationException: ldap.url.com:389 [Root exception
>   is java.net.UnknownHostException: ldap.url.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We satisfactorily resolved this by disabling this log4j property in the log4j configuration file in CAS:

```
 <Logger name="org.ldaptive.pool.BlockingConnectionPool" level="debug">
     <AppenderRef ref="console" />
 </Logger>
```

Another option may have been to create a log4j filter and target the particular message that was causing the tomcat file to become huge.

Answer (score 1):

I toggle between JDBC and LDAP/AD Handlers. Ensure that you comment out your ldap handler under:

**deployerConfigContext.xml** 
xpath:

> /beans
>
> > /bean[class=org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl]
> >
> > > /property[name=**authenticationHandlers**]
> > >
> > > > /list/

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how this is relevant to my question.  I'm looking for a solution that would prevent ldap from attempting to connect when/if there is no valid connection.

Comment: If you declare a  bean in Spring beans xml, then Spring will initialize it. I read that you commented out entire ldap section that caused Tomcat to crash. I see that you are setting up a connection pool along with validatePeriodically. Not sure if you want to comment out these beans or looking for specific properties? Also, please add the versions of CAS and Ldaptive.

Comment: We use Version 4.1 of ldapsdk and CAS version 4.2.7. In the deployerConfigContext.xml file there is no property named authenticationHandlers. We tried setting validatePeriodically to false but that didn't prevent CAS from continually attempting to connect to the ldap server.